# How to group records when rendering in HTML

Tags: javascript, html-table, servicenow, jelly

I have a set of records which are fetch from a backend and returned grouped by Category using a javascript code.

Actually those records are simply render in HTML by string concatenation as below :

knowledge KB number 1 - Short description - Categor1
knowledge KB number 2 - Short description - Categor2
knowledge KB number 3 - Short description - Categor1
knowledge KB number 4 - Short description - Categor5
knowledge KB number 5 - Short description - Category6
knowledge KB number 6 - Short description - Category7
knowledge KB number 7 - Short description - Category5

What I am trying to represent is the set of record above render in HTML as below :

**Category1** :
knowledge KB number 1 - Short description
knowledge KB number 3 - Short description

**Category 2:**
knowledge KB number 2 - Short description

**Category 5:**
knowledge KB number 4 - Short description
knowledge KB number 7 - Short description

**Category 6:**
knowledge KB number 5 - Short description

**Category 7:**
knowledge KB number 6 - Short description

How can I render my HTML in order that the Category is repeated only once per group

Here is below the sample code which represent them in concatained string :

```
GlideRecordSecure('u_kb_template_sharepoint_document');
                                               kb.addQuery('cmdb_ci',current.sys_id);
                                               kb.addQuery('latest',true);
                                               kb.orderBy('kb_category');
                                               kb.query();
                                               "/>

<j2:if test="$[kb.next()]" >
    <tr>
        <td class="label label_spacing">
            <span style="margin-right:3px; margin-left:1px;">$[SP]</span>
            ${gs.getMessage('Attached knowledge:')}
        </td>
        <td>
            <g2:evaluate>
                var hasMore = true;
                var category = kb.getDisplayValue('kb_category');
            </g2:evaluate>
            <j2:while test="$[hasMore]">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/nav_bult.gifx" alt="${gs.getMessage('Knowledge Base Article')}" />
                    <a class="obvious" target="_blank" href="$[kb.u_kb_url]">$[HTML:kb.number] - $[HTML:kb.short_description] - $[category]</a>
                </div>
                <g2:evaluate>
                    hasMore = kb.next();
                </g2:evaluate>
            </j2:while>
        </td>
    </tr>
</j2:if>
```

How can I update it to be grouped, did not find out ?

Note this script is part of Jelly element from ServiceNow

thanks

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and what your code looks like

Comment: I have past my sample code snipet which show the concatenated part, but could not get the way for grouping

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this isn't really an HTML issue, although you need to think of course how you want to visually represent this. I.e., the result will be a table with dynamic entries.

Now on the main question - 'How to show category only once' - you will need to do something like this in javascript (pseudo-code) - assume 'records' is an array containing those 7 records.

- records.sort(by category) --> assuming the strings are not yet concatenated, and you can access category as single variable
- records.foreach(item){
  compare previous item to current item
  if different create new HTML line, print category (otherwise stay in same line)
  if categories are same, just append the string
  previousitem = item
  }

--> So you sort your data by 'category', thus they are grouped next to each in the data. Then can compare each record with the next one so you can put the right logic for generating the respective HTML.

Comment: this is what i am not familar with on how to build this dynamic html, do you have sample?

Comment: So, I don't know Jelly and ServiceNow for this context, therefore this expands the scope of the original question. But basically, you need to infuse your logic at the right place of the HTML structure. I see you already have 'orderby(Category)' in your logic. Now you need to put things like (if previouscategory = currentcategory) in front of the <tr> tag. I.e., only have the '<tr>' tag when new category comes.